# Opencensus Advanced Aggregation

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, opencensus

When i create the metrics in google stackdriver driver monitoring. I do see list of options for aligner (which is under secondary aggregation) similar to aggregator but after implementing the opencensus metrics. I do see only delta and rate options alone.

Anybody faced the similar issue or Is their any option/parameter to set to fix this issue.

[Stackdriver Metrics Aligner Param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f6Ij.png)

Comment: For a better understanding if you share the definition of your metric will be helpful.

Comment: I don't see aligner options except delta and rate for any metrics.

Comment: I mean the whole definition. Keep in mind with more information and context it will be more helpful.

Comment: For a better interaction and a better experience follow the recommendations on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)